# Visual Studio 2019: where can I switch off "shared compilation"

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2019

I updated VS to the last version (16.8.1) and compilation process is very slow (10+ minutes, which got 20 sec before). I see on log and see that it delays on

> Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn

it pulls 100% CPU and all 16 Gb of memory. How to fix it and switch off this shared compilation feature?

**ADDED 11/17/2020**

I added

```
<UseSharedCompilation>False</UseSharedCompilation>
```

to every `<PropertyGroup>` for every project in my solution, but problem is not solved!

Comment: Not sure, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47590068/10871073) help?

Comment: What type of project, and what was the "before" version?

Comment: @dxiv solution has many projects: class libraries, web, azure functions... Before version - not sure, but previous version was installed approx 1 month ago

Comment: @AdrianMole added to my main question

Comment: @dxiv I have the same problem. In my case upgraded from one of the latest 16.7.x version to 16.8.1.

Comment: What I have noticed so far: on my machine `dotnet build` works but building from VS 16.8.1 does not. One difference: the first uses `C# Compiler version 3.5.0-beta4-20153-05 (20b9af91)` from `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201` (which is correct according to our `global.json`). And VS uses `C# Compiler version 3.8.0-5.20519.18 (4c195c3a)` from `Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe`. Could this point to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem after upgrading to VS 16.8.1. And while `dotnet build` continued to work, I couldn't compile my solution anymore: the compiler started by VS would eat up all the available memory (RAM) before finishing its job (see my comments on the question).

Setting `<UseSharedCompilation>False</UseSharedCompilation>` did not help either.

So I had to "downgrade" Visual Studio back to 16.7.8 by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64491972/331281). This helped me to have a working IDE back in place.